# How do I have docker run from the directory where the file is instead of /?

Tags: python, docker

This question is ought to have been asked before but I can't find an answer. I am running a python script from my terminal using docker, like:

```
docker run --rm img_name -v local_path:docker_path python docker_path_to_script/script.py
```

when I print from `script.py` where the script thinks it is using `cmd` it says:

```
/
```

which makes no sense (not sure what the official name of that is). This causes problems cuz I have relative paths within `script.py`. How do I have the script run from the correct location inside docker?

Comment: Just because you mounted a volume, doesn't change to working directory. For that, use `-w`.

Comment: On another note, my tool [`scuba`](https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/scuba) makes it easy to do this kind of thing. It handles the mount, working directory, and file ownership transparently. `scuba --image img_name python script.py`

Answer (score 1):

Set the default [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) in the image build

```
WORKDIR /docker_path
```

Set [`WORKDIR` with `-w`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir) when running the image

```
docker run -w /docker_path IMAGE COMMAND
```

Comment: what I find confusing is that I might in principle have `COMMAND` be any arbitrary python script in my docker image. Does that mean that I always have do have the `-w /docker_path` and `COMMAND=/docker_path/script.py` match? It just seems repetitive, silly and error prone. But if thats the I guess I'm suck with it...

Comment: Normally the script would deal with where it is launched from, so instead of using relative paths you reference paths from the location of the script. For example, in node.js the special variable `__dirname` can be used. In Python I think the equivalent is `__file__`.